# Cookie that mysteriously sets itself

Tags: php, cookies

When the condition of the first if statement is met, the cookie "c2" is also set. I'm really scratching my head here. Any ideas? FYI this is the only code that handles cookies on this page.

```
<?php
    //set cookies on correct answers
    if ( $_POST['answer-1'] == 'rob' ) :
        $c1 = 'correct';
        setcookie('c1', 'correct');
    endif;
    if ( $_POST['answer-2'] == 'blue' ) :
        $c2 = 'correct';
        setcookie('c2', 'correct');
    endif;

    //reset cookies
    if ( !empty($_POST['reset']) ) :
        $_COOKIE['c1'] = ''; 
        $_COOKIE['c2'] = '';
    endif;

    $c1c = $_COOKIE['c1'];
    $c2c = $_COOKIE['c2'];
?>
```

Comment: Shoot. I'm wrong. Same behavior when I change the name of the cookie.

Comment: And you did of course clear the cookies in the browser between tries ?

Comment: Yes. That is what //reset cookies does

Comment: As a sidenote - `setcookie('c1', 'correct')` - yeah you don't want that. Cookies are user-readable and user-modifyable. As soon as a user figures that out (and they will), they'll create the cookies `c2` up till `c99` and get their prize or whatever the purpose of this application is. Use the session to store user-specific data server-side.

Comment: "//reset cookies" simply sets the PHP superglobals, it does not clear the actual cookies. Cookie `c2` is dependent on your 2nd `if` statement, which is unrelated to the first `if` statement (it's not in an `else` block).

Comment: ^ accessing `$_COOKIE` does nothing for the cookies set in the browser ?

Comment: Thanks for that observation! I see how that got me all mixed up.

Comment: @adeneo no, `$_COOKIE` is merely a representation of the cookies received in the request for the current page. Cookies set in processing that request will also not be present in `$_COOKIE`, nor will changes in `$_COOKIE` reflect in actual cookies sent out in the response.

Comment: Thank codeCaster. This is a prototype, but I'll definitely include that in the next stage.

Comment: @CodeCaster - uhm, wasn't that exactly what I said? Changing `$_COOKIE` does not change the cookies set in the browser !

Comment: @adeneo no, it looked like a question rather than a statement. There's a question mark at the end of that sentence in your previous comment...

Comment: @CodeCaster - oh, okay, I'm sorry for the questionmark then, it was a statement, and it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
//reset cookies
if ( !empty($_POST['reset']) ) :
    $_COOKIE['c1'] = ''; 
    $_COOKIE['c2'] = '';
endif;
```

will reset the global `$_COOKIE` array with these values. But a page reload will still populate that again, as the cookies are still valid and stored in the browser.

In order to also delete them from the browser, you need:

```
//reset cookies
if ( !empty($_POST['reset']) ) :
    $_COOKIE['c1'] = ''; 
    $_COOKIE['c2'] = '';
    setcookie('c1', '', -3600);
    setcookie('c2', '', -3600);
endif;
```